# Which server connection is used by query window in Azure Data Studio / SQL Operations Manager

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-studio

I've recently started using Azure Data Studio (Formerly SQL Operations Studio) instead of SSMS.  I can't see an obvious way to tell which query windows relate to which connections.

Example:

I have 2 DB servers, and each has the same DB
server1.db1
server2.db1

Let's say I connect to both and open a query for each and run it.  Then I get confused and cant remember which connection is for window SQLQuery_1 and which is for SQLQuery_2.

I can see at the top of each window that they are connected to the DB "db1", but I don't know if it is for server1 or server2.  SSMS show's the server name.

Is there a way to make the server visible for a query window?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it at the bottom?  (outside of what you posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, it's shown in the bottom right hand side of the screen:
[image]

For example, in this picture, you can see I'm connected to the server `qebui` and the database `Sandbox`.

Comment: Yup I see it now.  Thanks :)